# could not resolve core-proto-0.0.8-alpha04.jar

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

When I create a project in Android Studio, Gradle can not sync the project and I receive the following error

> a problem occurred configuring root project 'Github(My project name)'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find bundletool-1.6.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.6.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.6.0/bundletool-1.6.0.jar
> Could not find core-proto-0.0.8-alpha04.jar (com.google.testing.platform:core-proto:0.0.8-alpha04).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/testing/platform/core-proto/0.0.8-alpha04/core-proto-0.0.8-alpha04.jar
> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at >https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

---

This photo is my problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI8g7.png)